# Expressing typeclass relations with functional dependencies in Haskell

Tags: haskell, typeclass, functional-dependencies

I want to express that I have 3 related typeclasses.

I have two files. First:

```
{-# LANGUAGE MultiParamTypeClasses, FunctionalDependencies #-}
module ModA where

class Class a b c | a -> b, b -> c where
    getB :: a -> b
    getC :: b -> c
```

Second:

```
{-# LANGUAGE MultiParamTypeClasses, FunctionalDependencies #-}
module B where

import qualified ModA

data A = A {f1::String}

data B = B {f2::String}

data C = C {f3::String}

instance ModA.Class A B C where
    getB a = B "hey"
    getC a = C "ho"

getABForMe = ModA.getB (A "boo")

getACForMe = ModA.getC (B "yo")
```

The error I get:

```
No instance for (ModA.Class a0 B C)
  arising from a use of `ModA.getC'
Possible fix: add an instance declaration for (ModA.Class a0 B C)
In the expression: ModA.getC (B "yo")
In an equation for `getACForMe': getACForMe = ModA.getC (B "yo")
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can make the functional dependency "circular":

```
class Class a b c | a->b, b->c, c->a where
    getB :: a -> b
    getC :: b -> c
```

so any one type parameter can be deduced from any of the others. But I'm not sure if you really want this; why not have just a type class with one fundep and one method, and make two instances of it (`instance Class A B` and `instance Class B C`)?

Comment: That's it! Worked perfectly, thank you. On the why part, the real code I work on is more involved than this little symmetrical example. Does this circular fundep solution count hackish?

Answer (score 2):

GHC cannot know the type of the first class parameter `a` in the call of `getC`. The call fixes `b` to be of type `B`, and the functional dependency then allows GHC to infer that `c` must be `C`. But no information on `a` is available.

Comment: How can I get around this then?